# Some Visual Studio 2010 or C# bug? Or am I just dreaming?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I just created a simple project with if statements to check if the statement is true, but then I stumbled into something weird.

This is my sample code

```
 if(x ==1)
    {
      do something;
    }

 else if( x==2)
    {
      do something;
    }
else if( x==3)
    {
      do something;
    }
else if( x==4)
    {
      do something;
    }

    {
      do something;
    }
```

nope, you read that right. And I typed that right also. I have left out the else statement, but I have created curly brackets for it. When I compile, it runs fine. Is this some kind of bug? Or am I just new to this? I just wanted to know. Thanks for all the answers

Comment: In general it is wise to assume that "select isn't broken" -- yes, compiler bugs do sometimes slip through, but this one is sufficiently obvious that had it been a bug, it would have been caught ten years ago.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Your last code block without an `if/else if` will execute.  Curly braces are for code separation, and don't require conditional/iteration or any other precursor to have meaning.

For an exageration to further explain my point:

```
{
    {
        Console.WriteLine("This works");
        int i;
    }
    // the variable i is out of scope and can't be referenced here
}
```

That is possible, as well.

As per **@slugonamission**'s comment, he brought up a great point.  The code block also creates a scope isolation for variables that are created inside of this code block.

Comment: To add to this, it creates a new scope block, so any variables you create inside that block will only be alive for the block they're defined in.

Comment: so does that mean that it will execute in the else statement?

Comment: @Nathan: no, it will execute unconditionally.

Comment: @slugonamission Great point, I have edited my post to include this valuable information.

Comment: @Nathan No, that code block will execute no matter what in that snippet of code.

Comment: @slugonamission: Your statement is incorrect. There is only a loose connection between local variable lifetime and the scope which contains them. A local variable that is a closed over outer variable of a lambda, or a local variable in an iterator block, or a local variable in an async block may all have their lifetimes extended beyond the point of time in which control is inside the scope. Conversely, the optimizer is permitted to shorten the lifetime of a local in a block if doing so is provably safe. You cannot *rely* on scope and lifetime being connected.

Comment: @Nathan: There is no such thing as an "else statement". The else and its consequence statement are part of the "if" statement; syntactically it is not a statement on its own.

Comment: @EricLippert - okay, lifetime was probably the wrong word to use in that statement. Mentally reword my point to be that the variables defined within the scope are effectively inaccessible outside of the block. It was meant more from a language point of view rather than a code generation viewpoint.

Comment: @EricLippert Very very interesting points there.  I just checked your profile and now I see how you are the C# expert. :D  Thank you for englightening us, I personally did not know your first comment.

Comment: @EricLippert thanks for the insight! I am still new to coding and I really just know how to code, I don't even know what you call them :)

Comment: @Shark: Now now, I'm sure there's more than one C# expert

Comment: @MattiVirkkunen Yeah, but how many principal developers are there for the C# compiler?!  Not too many, I imagine. :)  I feel as though I'm in the midst of a celebrity (call me a nerd if you wish).

Comment: @Shark: To answer your question: there are four people with that job title on the C#/VB compiler development team; there are a couple more on the IDE team I suspect; I have not got the org chart memorized. There are also a number of more senior Partner Developers on the compiler team. The compiler teams tend to have an unusually high concentration of senior developers.

Comment: @EricLippert What I would do to be a fly on the wall during one of your workdays...  Very interesting structure and explanation.  I wish I could spend an hour having a one-on-one conversation with you.

Comment: @Shark Meanwhile, you should be reading [Eric's blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/), if you're not already.

Answer (score 17):

It is always syntactically legal to surround any number of statements, including zero, in braces. The result is itself a statement.

You use this fact all the time; in fact, you used it half a dozen times in your example. The consequence of an "if" is always a single statement. In your example, that single statement is a block statement that contains another statement.

Answer (score 5):

A set of curly braces defines a block of statements. You're allowed to make any set of statements a block, although the most useful case is to use them after a control structure to put multiple statements inside it. The syntax for a block statement only requires that what comes after it is a statement - it can either be a single statement or a block statement (which is just another kind of statement).

A block outside a control statement doesn't do much besides creating a new scope for local variables. I like using them inside `case`s because cases don't automatically create a new scope.

```
switch (foo) {
    case 1: {
        int i; // local to this case!
        break;
    }
    case 2: {
        int i;
        break;
    }
}
```

Oh, and also this: [Don't rush to claim that you have found a bug](http://catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html#id478549)

Comment: To clarify your last statement (which is correct): there is a local variable declaration space associated with the entire switch, but that declaration space is *shared* by all the switch sections.

Answer (score 2):

That is valid syntax. Brackets by themselves merely indicate a separate block of scope; in this case completely unrelated to the `if - else if`'s.

So in your code the last block will always execute.